# Javascript roller on radio button's onclick

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have four radio buttons to select a country. When a user clicks on any of the radio button, I use Ajax to get the states of that country. In order to show the end user that we are processing the data, I use a roller image(gif).

When any user clicks on of country radio, in the method (onclick event of radio), **loadStates()**, I enable the roller image by setting it's display property to 'inline'.
Then send a request to the server using Ajax(for showing a working example, I have removed that code and have inserted a "sleep" instead, just to show that it takes some time).
Right after getting the result, I put back the display property to 'none'.

However it is not working. Can anybody tell me how to fix it ?

PS : I dont want to use jQuery for the time being, only Javascript please.

```
<html>
<head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = init;

    function init() {
       countryFunctions();
    }//init

    function countryFunctions() {
       var inputElems = document.forms[0].getElementsByTagName('input');
       for (var i = 0, j = inputElems.length; i < j; i++) {
          var elemName = inputElems[i].name;
          if ( typeof elemName != 'undefined' && elemName === 'country' ) {
             //inputElems[i].onmouseup = showRoller;
             inputElems[i].onclick = loadStates;
          }//if
       }//for
       return;
    }

   function loadStates() {
       var action = 'get_states';
       document.getElementById("fSpinner").style.display = "inline";
       //alert("hi........");
       var result = doLoad(action);
       document.getElementById("countryStates").innerHTML = result;
       document.getElementById("fSpinner").style.display = "none";
   }

   function doLoad(action) {//A dummy function just show what it returns (actually it is Ajax)
      sleep(7000);
      var value = "\
        <p>\
           Which state of the country would you like to go?\
        </p>\
        <select name=\"state\">\
            <option value=\"1362\">Delhi</option>\
            <option value=\"481\">Kerala</option>\
            <option value=\"666\">Punjab</option>\
            <option value=\"668\">Kashmir</option>\
       </select>";
      return(value);
   }

   function sleep(ms) {
      var unixtime_ms = new Date().getTime();
      while(new Date().getTime() < unixtime_ms + ms) {}
   }
 </script>
 <style type="text/css">
   #fSpinner { display:none; }
 </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    <p>What country do you belong to?</p>
    <p>
       <input name="country" value="in" type="radio">&nbsp;India&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <input name="country" value="au" type="radio">&nbsp;Australia&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <input name="country" value="nz" type="radio">&nbsp;New Zealand&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <input name="country" value="my" type="radio">&nbsp;Malaysia&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
       <span id="fSpinner">
           <img style="vertical-align:text-bottom;" src="http://107.20.148.146/shak/images/roller.gif">
       </span>
    </p>
    <div id="countryStates"></div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `sleep` function "blocks" the browser, the page is not refreshed until the function returns.

To simulate an asynchronous process, like an AJAX call, use `setTimeout` instead:

```
 function loadStates() {
   var action = 'get_states';
   document.getElementById("fSpinner").style.display = "inline";

   setTimeout( function() {
     var value = "\
       <p>\
          Which state of the country would you like to go?\
       </p>\
       <select name=\"state\">\
           <option value=\"1362\">Delhi</option>\
           <option value=\"481\">Kerala</option>\
           <option value=\"666\">Punjab</option>\
           <option value=\"668\">Kashmir</option>\
      </select>";
      document.getElementById("countryStates").innerHTML = value;
      document.getElementById("fSpinner").style.display = "none";
   }, 7000) ;
 }
```